# pump motor connection

Tags: pump

I want to run a 240v pump motor fed from 2 pole gfci 20 amp breaker (4 wire).

Also would like to add 120v 20 amp receptacle using 1 leg of 240v feed.

Can this be done or do I have to run separate 120 volt circuit?

Comment: Would you mind having the breaker trip if you were using the 120V circuit when the pump started? That's a very likely result of doing what you propose.

Comment: We need the nameplate rating of the pump motor.

Comment: I know my pumps specs a 20A breaker but has a rated current of only 6.5 amps max. But the starting surge is presumably a beast...they don't spec a 15A breaker for it.

Comment: Do you have a 4 wire feed running to the pump/receptacle location? Is the pump in a separate structure, or in the same structure as the breaker in question?

Comment: 4 wire feed to pump motor connection, pump separate, fed from house panel to outdoor location

Comment: The correct way to do that is to use your existing feed to a "sub panel" at the pump site, then have separate breakers in that sub panel for the pump and the receptacle. It's OK for the feeder to be 20A if you have already run the wire, then have the 20A GFCI branch breaker for the pump and a standard 20A branch breaker for the receptacle, then use a GFCI receptacle for that.